# Replication topology in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, san, load-balancing

Our first and current approach :

```
      Current Replication configuration is Active - Active
      and R/W is split on both node . This is asynch-replication.

      Primary node is having RW and Secondary Node is Read only 

      Both nodes are having dedicated storage node.
```

Now our second approach is to have single SAN for both nodes .

```
   In this approach , Primary node will point to SAN and whatever data being
   written in data directory of SAN , will get reflected in SN.
   This SAN has a redundancy that whenever it gets down,
   other SAN will come in picture . 

   This will eliminate the usage of 1 storage drive and hence reducing cost.
```

Now can anyone tell which is the best approach here with various justified reason.

My Server configuration is :

1. RHEL 7.2
2. 48 GB RAM
3. 8 CORE CPU
4. MySQL 5.7 enterprise edition

**EDIT**

In SAN with data directory shared , only one node can stay alive and other node will be dead. So replication is no longer required.

Comment: First, list the possible failures, then compute the likelihood of each.  Finally analyze your approaches to see which one is less likely to "fail".

Comment: Single shared storage is less likely to fail.. Because once PN goes down , SN will bring up manually and it will then act as a active node.

Comment: Do _not_ share the data; MySQL has no code to do the sync.  You can have two separate data directories on a single SAN, but then the  SAN is a single-point-of-failure.

Comment: Yes true...SAN is single point of failure.But we have experienced very rare cases where SAN gets down. If it is down we have mirror for SAN

Comment: Less chance of failure if each MySQL writes to separate disk system.

Comment: But in this case replication will be introduced and we may face replication delay , inconsistency . Moreover 2 storage system will be in use. Im using classic file based replication and not using NDB

Comment: List the goals, in priority order, that you are trying to achieve.  Keep in mind that there is _no_ solution that solves _all_ goals _simultaneously_.